# How to access variables inside a function from outside in another function in typescript?

Tags: angular, function, typescript, angular6

In my html page onchange, im just calling a method by passing parameters. After retrieving the value, onclick of another button Im calling function2. I need to use the variable from function in function2 in the same class. Im using angular 6 & typescript. My ts file is given below.

```
 export class component extends Lifecycle {
  cc1: string;
  constructor (){}
  Function (cc1,cc2)
  {
   this.cc1 = cc1;
   // return cc1;
   }

  Function2 (){
      console.log(cc1);
    }
  }
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `this` keyword inside any method to access to any property or method related to class.

```
export class component extends Lifecycle {
    cc1: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    Function(cc1, cc2) {
        this.cc1 = cc1;
        // return cc1;
    }

    Function2() {
        console.log(this.cc1);
    }
}
```

> You have to call `super` if you extend the class

Answer (score 2):

In `Function2`, you would use `this.cc1` as shown below (note that I renamed the parameters passed to `Function1` to clarify their difference from the class-level variable)

```
export class component extends Lifecycle {
  cc1: string;

  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  Function1 (_cc1, _cc2) {
    this.cc1 = _cc1;
  }

  Function2 () {
    console.log(this.cc1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Function 2

```
Function2 (){
      console.log(this.cc1);
    }
  }
```